# Laravel Elixir combining Sass files in wrong order

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-elixir

I have three Sass files in the same directory: `_include.scss`, `app.scss` and `partials.scss`.

Both `app.scss` and `partials.scss` have an import at the first line:

```sass
@import "include";
```

And at the first line in `_include.scss`:

```sass
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.scss',
        'partials.scss'
    ]);
});
```

Bootstrap's and my own Sass code is combined into the same CSS file (`public/css/app.css)`. The only problem is that Bootstrap's CSS is inserted after `app.scss`, so any changes I make will be overridden by Bootstrap if they collide. `partials.scss` is inserted at the correctly at the bottom.

What causes this? I have, as far as I can see, the exact same setup in other projects without this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the doubled `@import "include";` statement:

> Both `app.scss` and `partials.scss` have an import at the first line

There is an [issue for import once](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/139) semantics in SASS, but it is still not resolved. I would suggest to include the library only in one place until the issue is resolved.

**Update:** There is an [informative blog post](http://paul.wellnerbou.de/2015/05/18/avoid-multiple-imports-of-the-same-scss-file-with-sass/) on the topic as well, which might help you to find a workaround that suits you.

Comment: I'll confirm this tomorrow and accept your answer. Thanks.